# Why is there comma in my slice

Tags: python, python-2.7, strptime

When I did slice for my `date/month/year`,
there's always this `"()"` & `","`.
May I know how do I get rid of it?
user input  = 21/12/1999
output = (1999,12,21)

```
def get_dateOfBirth():
    while True:
        dateOfBirth_input = raw_input("Please enter your date of birth in DD/MM/YYYY format: ")
        try:
            result = strptime(dateOfBirth_input, "%d/%m/%Y")
        except ValueError:
            print "Please Key in the valid Date Of Birth"
        else:
            return result[:3]

dateOfBirth = get_dateOfBirth()
birthDate = dateOfBirth[2:3]
birthMonth = dateOfBirth[1:2]
birthYear = dateOfBirth[:1]

print "date is" + str(birthDate)
print "month is" + str(birthMonth)
print "year is" + str(birthYear)
```

Comment: You say your output is "(1999,12,21)". But the code you've shown us only has one print statement, and that only prints an error message. Please show the whole code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_dateOfBirth` returns a tuple, and performing slicing on a tuple gives you a tuple.

If you want `birthDate`, `birthMonth`, and `birthYear` to be regular integers, instead of tuples containing one integer apiece, use indexing instead of slicing.

```
dateOfBirth = get_dateOfBirth()
birthDate = dateOfBirth[2]
birthMonth = dateOfBirth[1]
birthYear = dateOfBirth[0]

#bonus style tip: add a space between 'is' and the number that follows it
print "date is " + str(birthDate)
print "month is " + str(birthMonth)
print "year is " + str(birthYear)
```

Result:

```
Please enter your date of birth in DD/MM/YYYY format: 21/12/1999
date is 21
month is 12
year is 1999
```

Answer (score 2):

The `time.strptime` function actually returns a `struct_time` object, but that object will behave like a tuple if you treat it like a tuple. So you can use slicing & indexing to access its attributes, as well as the standard syntax for attribute access, eg `dateOfBirth.tm_year`. Using the attribute access syntax is clearer than using the tuple access, and you don't need to worry about remembering what order the different attributes are in. OTOH, the tuple-based approach will often result in shorter (if more cryptic) code.

In this version of your program I've used the `*` unpacking operator (aka the "splat" operator) to pass the desired fields to the `format` function; the `struct_time` object will behave like a tuple in that context. I've also imported the `readline` module, which automatically adds line editing to `raw_input()`, which is nice if the user makes a mistake & needs to re-enter the data. However, `readline` isn't supported on all platforms.

I've also moved the prompt string out of the `raw_input()` call to make the code look a bit neater, and optimised your `try:...except` block slightly.

```
from time import strptime
import readline

def get_dateOfBirth():
    prompt = "Please enter your date of birth in DD/MM/YYYY format: "
    while True:
        dateOfBirth_input = raw_input(prompt)
        try:
            return strptime(dateOfBirth_input, "%d/%m/%Y")
        except ValueError:
            print "Please Key in the valid Date Of Birth"

dateOfBirth = get_dateOfBirth()
print "day is {2}\nmonth is {1}\nyear is {0}".format(*dateOfBirth)
```